# Using main scrollbar to scroll inner div then scroll rest of page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a container div `right-col` inside of my `hero` div, that holds two inner divs. The inner divs are sticky and the container div is scrollable to give the illusion of cards sliding up.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="hero">
        <div class="left-col">h</div>
        <div class="right-col">
            <div class="top">1st card</div>
            <div class="bottom">2nd Card</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="projects">a</div>
    <div class="contact-footer"></div>
    <div></div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: black;
}
.hero {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.left-col{
    width: 40vw;
    background-color: black;
    height: 100vh;
}
.right-col{
    min-width: 60vw;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100vh;
}
.top{
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: chartreuse;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
.bottom{
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: orange;
    position: sticky;
    top: 10%;
}

.projects{
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: crimson;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

However, the scroll bar is on the inside of the div `right-col` and independent from the main scrollbar. Is there a way that I can use the main scrollbar to scroll through the container div till it reaches the bottom then continues to scroll through the rest of the page? Possibly using js or jquery?

Answer (score -1):

You could try adding the following css. It will make the inner scroll bar 0 width, so basically it will be invisible but still work.

```
.hero ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
}
```

If you need something more specific you could try using the [scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event) event to possibly synchronize both scroll bars or something.

Comment: Yes, but that will just hide the inner scroll bar, id like to control the inner scroll using the main scroll bar

Comment: Then you'll have to get fancy using the scroll event as i mentioned either with vanilla javascript or jquery and attaching an event listener so that moving one scroll bar also changes the other.

Comment: your solution also will only work for webkit browsers. So a large quantity of browser would not eb affected this way.